# Compare 2 Excel Sheets and output the difference on a third

Tags: excel, compare

Hy there!

I do have a sheet where all the Products are listed:
[image: excelsheet1]

In the second Sheet I do have a Lookup, when the user puts the `Artikelnummer` in column A the lookup autamticly fills the columns B & C

```
=SVERWEIS(A2;Gesamtliste!A:C;2)
```

[image: excelsheet2]

Now I need a formula which compares Sheet2 with Sheet1 and shows the difference in Sheet3

The Output should be similar to this:
[image: exclesheet3]

Ive done a lot of research, but couldnt find any proper formular.
THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `Power Query`.

First turn Sheet1 and Sheet2 into tables.

Then create a new query linked to each table in `Power Query`.

Finally, merge the two linked table queries using an `OUTER JOIN` on Artikelnummer and output to a new sheet.

This will produce any data that is included on Sheet1 but not Sheet2.